# Does a join between two tables always happen over a foreign key?

Tags: sql, join

Does a join between two tables always happen over a foreign key?

Answer (score 5):

In a word, no.

You can do a join on any condition, whether or not it is or uses a foreign key. In theory, it can be on no condition at all (a Cartesian join), although that's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can use any column make a join. FK is preferred for greater performance, as it has an index on it.